# <p:commandLink> is not working when i use onClick event

Tags: primefaces

Hope you all will be fine. The scenerio is that i have a page on which you upload picture and then remove it. I used code like this

```html
<h:panelGrid columns="5"
             border=""
             width="20%"
             style="position: absolute; top: 50px;"
             columnClasses="asteriskColumns, nameColumns" >

    <h:outputText value="*" />
    <h:outputText value="Map: " />
    <p:fileUpload id="cityMap"
                  description="Image"
                  update="city messages"
                  allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                  auto="true"
                  fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

    </p:fileUpload>

    <p:graphicImage id="city"
                    value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                    width="80"
                    height="50"
                    cache="false">

        <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />

    </p:graphicImage>

    <p:commandLink update="city"
                   action="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"
                   style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline"
                   onclick="">

        <h:outputText value="remove" />

    </p:commandLink>

    <h:outputText value="*" />
    <h:outputText value="Image1: " />
    <p:fileUpload id="cityImage1"
                  description="Image"
                  update="Image1 messages"
                  allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                  auto="true"
                  fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

    </p:fileUpload>

    <p:graphicImage id="Image1"
                    value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                    width="80"
                    height="50"
                    cache="false" >

        <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />

    </p:graphicImage>

    <p:commandLink update="Image1"
                   action="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"
                   style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline"
                   onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete the picture?')) { return false; }; return true;">

        <h:outputText value="remove" />

    </p:commandLink>

    <h:outputText value="*" />
    <h:outputText value="Image2: " />
    <p:fileUpload id="cityImage2"
                  description="Image"
                  update="Image2 messages"
                  allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                  auto="true"
                  fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

    </p:fileUpload>

    <p:graphicImage id="Image2"
                    value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                    width="80"
                    height="50"
                    cache="false" >

        <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />

    </p:graphicImage>

    <p:commandLink update="Image2"
                   action="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"
                   style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline"
                   onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete the picture?')) { return false; }; return true;">

        <h:outputText value="remove" />

    </p:commandLink>
.....
```

The problem is every thing is working fine if i use

```
onclick=""
```

But when I use

```
onclick="if (! confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete the picture?') ) { return false;}; return true; "
```

Then the remove not work. Why? Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

I am using PrimeFaces 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use p:commandLink. Although i did it in this way and it is working fine

```
<h:outputText value="*" />
<h:outputText value="Map: " />
<p:fileUpload id="cityMap"
              description="Image"
              update="city messages"
              allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
              auto="true"
              fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}" >

</p:fileUpload>

<p:graphicImage id="city"
                value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}"
                width="80"
                height="50"
                cache="false">

    <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />

</p:graphicImage>

<h:commandLink value="remove"
               title="Remove Picture"
               style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline"
               onclick="if (! confirm('Are you sure, you want to remove picture?') ) { return false;}; return true; ">

     <f:ajax event="click"
             render="city"
             listener="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"/>

 </h:commandLink>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem and setting ajax=false dosen't work for me.

The solution I found is to change **onclick** by **onstart**.

It seems that primefaces uses onclick to process ajax action, so when onclick returns a value (**either true or false**) the whole action aborts.

with onstart if it returns true the action continue to execute and if false it aborts.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this :

```
<p:commandLink update="Image1" action="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"
   onstart="return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete the picture?')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks strange 'cause you're trying this (kind of) in Java way but you're complicating `onclick="if (! confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete the picture?') ) { return false;}; return true; "` - you don't use right the javascript confirm function.
You could write:

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete the picture?')"
```

, but since you're using Primefaces(by the way - you could upgrade to 3.0.M4) you could use the confirmDialog component:

```
<p:commandButton value="Delete picture" onclick="confirmation.show()" type="button"/>
<p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure, you want to delete the picture?"  
            showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode"  
            header="Initiating deleting process" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">  

    <p:commandButton value="Yes Sure" update="<some component you want to update>" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"  actionListener="#{myBean.deleteMethod}" />  
    <p:commandButton value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />   

</p:confirmDialog>
```

It's indeed more to write but it's surely more elegant and nice!

Answer (score 1):

Return true and false does not need on there 
just use simple as following code

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete the picture?')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `p:commandLink` in that tag you will find ajax; set `ajax=false`, then it will work fine.